# Silverlight WebClient file upload issue in Chrome

Tags: silverlight, http, webclient

I have a strange issue about WebClient class in Silverlight app when using Chrome. I can successfully upload file with IE but when I use Chrome its failing. When I digg into it I see that WebClient (or Chrome I don't know who is responsible for this) is adding "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" header to request when using Chrome, but its not added on IE.
Because of that header, server side app is throwing following expcetion:

System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

> [InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current
>   state of the object.]
>   System.Web.HttpValueCollection.ThrowIfMaxHttpCollectionKeysExceeded()
>   +2420886    System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding) +58
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +159
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The URL-encoded form data is not valid.] 
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +217
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +104

Following is the code that I use in Silverlight

```
![private void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream data)
        {
            var uri = this.ResolveUri(apiMethod, arguments);
            ub.Query = string.Format("filename={0}", fileName);
            WebClient c = new WebClient();
            c.OpenWriteCompleted += (sender, e) =>
            {
                PushData(data, e.Result);
                e.Result.Close();
                data.Close();
            };
            c.OpenWriteAsync(ub.Uri);
        }
        private void PushData(Stream input, Stream output)
        {
            byte\[\] buffer = new byte\[4096\];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
```

---

Request using Chrome which is failed:
[image: chrome]
Request using IE which is success:
[image: ie]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have upload functions that are almost identical to your example above.  I see the same requests in fiddler as you do but it seems to work fine from both browsers (no errors and files are uploaded).  What are you doing on the server side?  Maybe that is where the problem lies.

Also, you probably could try playing with changing the content-type on the client WebClient request.

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
c.Headers.Add("Content-Type","whatever/you-want");
```

Comment: thanks Doug, this solve the problem (content-type:"text/html"), but it should be set by framework, isn't it?

Comment: @Yucel, if by framework you mean SL, it appears that many of the default header settings are left to the host browser to control.  See [MSDN WebHeaderCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webheadercollection(v=vs.95).aspx) for more information.  _Many of these restricted headers are set by the web browser that hosts the Silverlight application._